# Use for loop and local array with each item in *ngFor

Tags: angular

```js
//this.http.get("https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ImagingDocumentTypes')/items?$select=Title,Image,Source/Title,System/Title&$orderBy=Title&$expand=Source,System&$filter=System/Title eq '" + this.item + "'").subscribe(data => {
//this.doctypes = data['value'];

//EXAMPLE OUTPUT IS: 
this.doctypes = [{
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (MN)"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }, {
    "Title": "Lafayette Savings Bank"
  }],
  "Title": "Commercial Loans",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }, {
    "Title": "Old National"
  }],
  "Title": "Checks",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (MN)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Old National"
  }],
  "Title": "HR Documents",
}]


for (let i = 0; i < this.doctypes.length; i++) {
  let sources = this.doctypes[i].Source;
  let sourcesarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    console.log(sources[i].Title)
    sourcesarr.push(sources[i].Title)
    console.log(sourcesarr)
  }
  sourcesarr.sort()
}

//})
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.39/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="modalheader">Document Types</th>
    <th class="modalheader">Sources</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let doctype of doctypes">
    <td>{{doctype.Title}}</td>
    <td>
      <!-- WANT EVERY SOURCE FOR EACH DOCTYPE HERE -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have built a table for types of documents and their sources.

Using `*ngFor`, I am looping through an object array named `this.doctypes` and want to get each `doctype`s sources. Using a common `for` loop, I can get each source that uses the document type and push it to a local array. I am clearing this array and pushing each source after iterating over each document type.

However, I can't change `sourcesarr` to be a global variable (to be accessed by a second `*ngFor`) because it will end up storing the sources for only the last doctype iterated over.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you post your template file for this component?

Comment: @KylePfromer Code snippet has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this might help. Let me know if this works:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="modalheader">Document Types</th>
    <th class="modalheader">Sources</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let doctype of doctypes">
    <td>{{doctype.Title}}</td>
    <td>
        <div *ngFor="let source of doctype.Source">
            {{source.Title}}
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!